# How to show records from database in html table

Tags: php, html

I'm selecting records from database and showing it as

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" >Name</td>
        <td align="center" >Contact</td>    
    </tr>
    <?php  
    foreach($rowset as $row) 
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['contact'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php   
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

It is displayed as

```
|  Name  |  Contact  |
   a        9956874525
   b        9856426569
   c        9865989657
   d        8956789565
   e        8956879899
   f        8985656465
```

Here each record is shown in separate `<tr>`

But now i've to show the records in such a way that ,two records are shown in a single `<tr>`

So my design should be

```
|  Name  |  Contact  |    |  Name  |  Contact  |
   a        9956874525       b        9856426569
   c        9865989657       d        8956789565
   e        8956879899       f        8985656465
```

What changes should i do in above code? Please help

Comment: Not to be mean but in your profile it's stated *I'm a web developer like to solve complex problems.*. Umm.. You can do it! XD

Answer (score 1):

You need create an counter to count how many times you have printed the data.

Maybe like this (not tested yet):

```
<?php
     $i = 0;
     foreach($rowset as $row) 
     {   
       if($i % 2 == 0)  echo "<tr>";  
?>  
          <td align="left"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $row['contact'];?></td>
<?php
       if($i % 2 == 0) echo "</tr>"; $i++;     
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

modify the code like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" >Name</td>
        <td align="center" >Contact</td>    
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i=1;
    foreach($rowset as $row) 
    {
      if($i%2==1) {
    ?>

    <tr>

   <?php } ?>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['contact'];?></td>
    <?php  if($i%2==0) { ?>
    </tr>
     <?php } ?>
    <?php   

   $i++; }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the loop conditionally on the basis of indexes.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Name</td>
        <td align="center">Contact</td>
        <td align="center">Name</td>
        <td align="center">Contact</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php  
    foreach($rowset as $i=>$row) {
        if($i!=0 && $i%2 == 0) {
    ?>
        </tr><tr>
    <?php } ?>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['contact'];?></td>

    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop instead

```
$num_contacts = sizeof($rowset);
for($i = 0; $i < $num_contacts; $i++)
{
   if($i%2 == 0)
      echo "<tr>";
   ?>
 <td align="left"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
 <td align="left"><?php echo $row['contact'];?></td>
 <?php
    if($i%2 == 0)
      echo "</tr>";
 }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Its the appropriate way..

<table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <?php  
    foreach($rowset as $i=>$row) {
        if($i!=0 && $i%2 == 0) {
    ?>
        </tr><tr>
    <?php } ?>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['contact'];?></td>

    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First connect to database using: **$con = mysql_connect(host,username,password);**
2. Select Database : **mysql_select_db(dbname,$con);**
3. Write a query: **$qselect = mysql_query("select * from mytable");**
4. Now Let's start displaying in a HTML Table:

   ```
   <table>

   <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Address</th>
   </tr>

   <?php

    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($qselect))
    {
      extract($result);
   ?>

   <tr>
     <td><?= $name?></td>

     <td><?= $addr?></td>
   </tr>

   <?php
    }
   ?>
   </table>
   ```

Note: $name and $addr are field names from mysql table.